# Is there a way to have a default search criteria

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

I am using reactive search to search against my elastic search index. I would like to have one field in the index be a default. For instance, in this app at the root level, you choose a project. When you progress farther into the app you can search. Right now, you are searching against all projects.

I have made a toggle button that I hide with css. This approach is a hack, and works until I clear all filters. That toggle button that no one sees clears the project, then I see results from all projects again.

```
        <ToggleButton
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          componentId="project"
          dataField="project"
          defaultSelected={[projectId]}
          URLParams={false}
          multiSelect={false}
          showFilter={false}
          data={[
            { label: 'Project', value: projectId },
          ]}
          className="project"
        />
```

Is there a way to set a default search criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure, You can set default search criteria for this,
Set defaultQuery in ReactiveList component and match the value which has to be default.

Like this:

```
<ReactiveList
    componentId="results"
    dataField={datafield}
    sortBy={sort}
    react={{
        and: Query
    }}
    defaultQuery={this.defaultQuery}
/>

this.defaultQuery = function() {
    return {
        match: { dataField: "Value" }
    }
};
```